# Where was Gendry born?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *Game of Thrones S08E04 The Last of the Starks*, Gendry is

> legitimized by Daenerys & pronounced as Gendry Baratheon, the Lord of Storms End.

When Gendry finds Arya, he tells him that his earlier name was Gendry Rivers.

> and now it's Gendry Baratheon & proposes marriage to her.

As far as I know, Gendry was born in Kings Landing.

Bastards of Kings Landing are named Waters. Bastards of Riverrun are named Rivers & Bastards of Stormlands are called Storm.

So, where exactly was Gendry born?  Was this a plot error from D&D?